# Can XGBoost handle a custom objective where the 2nd derivative can be negative?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, boosting, cart, loss-functions

I am going through the [introduction](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html) to XGBoost page, and there is a section where they derive the *optimal* value of the leaf node, for a given tree structure.

To quote the specific section,

> In this equation, $w_j$ are independent with respect to each other, the form $G_j w_j + \frac{1}{2} (H_j + \lambda) w_j^2$ is quadratic and the best $w_j$ for a given structure $q(x)$ and the best objective reduction we can get is:
> $$ w^*_j = -\frac{G_j}{H_j + \lambda}$$....

For context, $G_j w_j + \frac{1}{2} (H_j + \lambda) w_j^2$ is the summand of the objective, $G_j$ is the sum of sample gradients in leaf $j$ WRT leaf values evaluated at existing trees, $H_j$ is the sum of Hessian terms in leaf $j$, $w_j$ is the leaf value, and $\lambda$ is the L2-regularization constant.

Clearly $w^*_j$ is the stationary point of $w_j$ in the objective.

Now, the second derivative of the objective is $H_j + \lambda$. But a stationary point is only a *minimum* if the second derivative is positive. In this case, their equation for $w^*_j$ is only a *minimizer* of the objective if $H_j > 0$ (let's ignore $\lambda$ for simplicity here). If $H_j$ is negative, or zero, then $w^*_j$ may, in fact, be a maximizer or a saddle point.

I find that the second derivative of most typical objective functions is strictly positive. The common examples that come to mind are MSE ($1$), cross-entropy ($p (1 - p)$ where $p = \sigma(y)$), Poisson objective ($\frac{t}{y^2}$ where $t$ is the target). Which is a happy coincidence. But, as soon as we introduce a custom objective with a 2nd derivative that can be negative or zero, then XGBoost can no longer handle this. Is this true?

The reason I am asking this is because I am currently trying to train a model with a custom objective with Hessian that is sometimes $<0$. And I am getting the wrong behavior for very obvious cases. I even contrived a dataset where the leaf values should all be pushed to $-\infty$, and are instead being pushed to $+\infty$. One "hacky" solution I found, that actually worked, is to replace the Hessian with its absolute value. Though I can't theoretically justify why it works.

**Is XGBoost unable to handle custom objectives with negative second derivatives? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?**

Comment: "I am currently trying to train a model with a custom objective with Hessian that is sometimes <0" - in those cases I guess you want to pick an end of the allowable interval (maybe $\pm\infty$ in the "raw" space?)?  That might be complicated to get to work correctly inside an existing framework.  Can you share this objective function?

Comment: The MAE loss has a similar issue, where hessian is identically zero.  That gets handled by most packages by just setting the hessian to 1 for split construction, which amounts to doing vanilla gradient descent (without the second derivative "enrichment"), although also then leaf values get set differently: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2128#issuecomment-492053052

Comment: I think you’ve hit on the major problems with using a loss function that isn’t PSD with xgboost. As you’ve written, the software uses a quadratic approximation, which can be very poor for a non-convex loss.

Comment: @BenReiniger The objective is basically $\sigma(y_i) * \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ is some real number (+ve or -ve) associated with sample $i$. So the Hess is $\sigma(y_i) (1 - \sigma(y_i)) (1 - 2 \sigma(y_i)) \alpha_i$. Here, $\sigma(y) = (1 + e^{-y})^{-1}$.

I don't understand what you mean by "pick an end of the allowable interval". Can you clarify please? I can't just subset on samples which have positive Hess, or I will get bad results. I have to include all of them. Currently, I got a good result by replacing Hess with its absolute value, but IDK why this worked

Comment: @Sycorax I see why quadratic approximation would be bad for one tree. But it does this multiple times for subsequent boosted trees. Doesn't that just make this similar to Newton method? I think the problem is just that, if the Hess is negative, then their stationary point is a maximizer, not a minimizer of the objective, and it's having the opposite of desired behavior.

Comment: Newton's method also does not perform well when the Hessian is not PSD. The last sentence in your Comment seems like a good explanation for the behavior that you describe in your Question. It seems like you understand that choosing weights that *maximize the loss* would mean that the model does not make good predictions; doing this for several trees seems like this phenomenon would compound at each round of boosting. What requires more explanation?